# Why use Column with Rows instead of Grid?

Tags: formatting

In general, what are the advantages of using Grid versus a combination of Column and Row? Is Grid better in some situations but not others?

For example, is there any reason why one would do this:

```
Grid[{{"Some text I want above a formula:"},
      {Integrate[f[x], x]}}]
```

versus this:

```
Column[{Row[{"Some text I want above a formula:"}], 
        Row[{Integrate[f[x], x]}]}]
```

Comment: It seems `Grid` is natural way of dealing with arrays while it is more convinient to use `Rows` for rows with different quantity of columns.
Of course with SpanFrom~ and others You can do whatever You need in the way You want to. I don't see any limitations favouring any of this ways. Do what is shorter and more convinient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several differences in behaviour.  One is that `Row` will be line-wrapped if it does not fit the notebook window:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Grid` will not.

Also with `Grid` the alignment is global, so the $n^\textrm{th}$ elements in each row will always line up vertically with each other.  This is not the case with several `Row`s in one `Column`.

```
table = Table[RandomInteger[13, 10], {5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Grid` allows merging several grid cells too (see e.g. `SpanFromLeft`).  This is just some of the most obvious differences.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Grid also allows you to algorithmically specify things like background coloring (although you need a degree in math & magic to get your specs right).

Answer (score 19):

If I am making something ad hoc I often use `Column` and `Row` but later re-write as `Grid` once I have settled on what I want. I find `Grid` easier to maintain and more flexible.

`Grid` and `Column` are both `GridBox` whereas `Row` is `RowBox`. There are some limitations with `RowBox` -- for example one thing that comes to mind is limited `FrameStyle` compared to what is available in `GridBox`

```
Row[{1, 22, 333}, Background -> Red, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Dashed]]

Grid[{{1, 22, 333}}, Background -> Red, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Dashed]]
```

[image]

---

For some reason I always seem to find it easier to position elements in a `Grid` cell than a `Row` -- maybe just lack of perseverance on my part (?). `Row` allows numbered alignments `Alignment->{-0.5,0.5}` but I don't really see the point. On the other hand this would be useful in `Grid` but a known bug since at least V7 prevents it from working.

Comment: Thank you @mike-honeychurch for your excellent answer. I would like to have accepted your answer to my question as well, but it turns out there can only be one.