# Making a presentable BarChart

Tags: plotting, overlay

I've been asked to reproduce a bar chart generated in Excel in *Mathematica*. The original Excel chart looks like this;

[image: Excel chart]

My *Mathematica* version looks like this;

[image: Mathematica chart]

There are a couple of things wrong that I'd like to fix;

1. The `BarChart` and `ListPlot` overlay doesn't seem to match up.
2. The `ChartLabels` seem to have disappeared on the `BarChart`.
3. Is there a nice way to make the ticks on the left and right sides match up (like when the Excel chart matches 9 % on the left to 90 % on the right)?
4. I can't get the box and line to center align to the text in the legend.

Questions 1 and 2 are what I really need to fix, but 3 and 4 would be nice to have. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code I used to generate my chart;

```
purple = RGBColor[97/255, 16/255, 106/255];
orange = RGBColor[245/255, 132/255, 31/255];
labels = 
  {
    "FY15 Q1/2", "FY15 Q3/4", "FY16 Q1/2", "FY16 Q3/4", 
    "FY17 Q1/Q2", "FY17 Q3/Q4", "FY18 Q1/2", "FY18 Q3/4"
  };
starvedTime = {7.55, 11.23, 8.58333, 6.88833, 4.65167, 1.89, 6.49833, 1.95};
satTime = {70.1483, 81.1467, 81.115, 86.5483, 84.6833, 90.685, 79.6017, 91.0133};

plot1 = BarChart[starvedTime, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 12}, 
  ChartStyle -> purple, 
  BaseStyle -> "Text", 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
  FrameTicks -> {False, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Smelter Starved Time (%)", "Text"], None, None}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Smelter Starved Time by 6 Month Period: Base Case", 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[Style[#, "Text"] & /@ labels, Below], None},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0}, 
  BarSpacing -> 1];

plot2 = ListPlot[satTime, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {60, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> orange, 
 Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
 FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  {None, None, None, Style["Smelter Operating at Constraint Rate (%)", "Text"]}, 
 BaseStyle -> "Text", 
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 ImageSize -> Large];

box = Graphics[{purple, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 12];
text = Style["   Smelter Starved (%)   ", "Text"];
line = Graphics[{orange, Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> {30, Automatic}];
text2 = Text[Style["    % Time Smelter at Constraint Rate (%)       ", "Text"]];
legend = Row[{box, text, line, text2}];

Column[{Overlay[{plot1, plot2}], legend}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answers to your 4 questions step by step to see how each of these changes the composite plot:

**1.** The image padding around the two images differs so you need to set a fixed value for each. With `ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {50, 10}}` as an option for both plots I get this:

[image]

**2.** `ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, "Text"] & /@ labels, Below],ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 10}},`

[image]

**3.** in plot #2 add `PlotLabel -> ""`

[image]

**4.** I [almost always prefer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19555/why-use-column-with-rows-instead-of-grid/19564#19564) `Grid` to `Row`:

```
box = Graphics[{purple, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 12];
text = "Smelter Starved (%)";
line = Graphics[{orange, Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> {30, Automatic}];
text2 = "% Time Smelter at Constraint Rate (%)";
legend = Grid[{{box, text, line, text2}}, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center},
BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"], Spacings -> {{0, 0.5, 2}, 0}];
```

[image]

**Finishing touches**

Bar chart plot ranges go from 0.5 to length of data + 0.5. So set the plot range of your bar chart to `PlotRange -> {{0.5, 8.5}, {0, 12}}` and for the list plot to `PlotRange -> {{0.5, 8.5}, {60, 100}}`. Now set your data range for `ListPlot` to be `DataRange -> {1, 8}`. This will ensure that the point coincide with the middle of your bars.

```
plot1 = BarChart[starvedTime, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, BarSpacing -> 1, 
   BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, Below], ChartStyle -> purple, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Smelter Starved Time (%)", None, None}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{#, "", {0, 0.01}} & /@ Range[0.5, 8.5, 1], {0, 3, 
      6, 9, 12}, None, None}, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Plain, 12], 
   GridLines -> {None, {3, 6, 9}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 10}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12], 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Smelter Starved Time by 6 Month Period: Base Case", 13], 
   PlotRange -> {{0.5, 8.5}, {0, 12}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   Ticks -> None];

plot2 = ListPlot[satTime, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> False,
    BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   DataRange -> {1, 8}, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, {60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Plain, 12], 
   FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, 
     "Smelter Operating at Constraint Rate (%)"}, ImageSize -> 600, 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 10}}, Joined -> True, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.5, 8.5}, {60, 100}}, PlotStyle -> orange, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["", 13]];
```

[image]

Note #1. there is scope for you to match the fonts of the Excel chart.

Note #2. `Labeled` could be used instead of `Column`.

Note #3. To completely match the Excel chart you actually need the grid lines to be used in the bar chart rather than the list plot.

Note #4. Added some ticks between the bars.

Note #5. Corrected labels: `"FY17 Q1/Q2", "FY17 Q3/Q4",`

Comment: Great tips. I particularly like the use of Grid, I haven't really done that before. I'm using a Stylesheet to match the fonts.

Answer (score 21):

Often I find it easier to construct such graphics directly from `Graphics` primitives.

First your data:

```
purple = RGBColor[97/255, 16/255, 106/255];
orange = RGBColor[245/255, 132/255, 31/255];
labels = {"FY15 Q1/2", "FY15 Q3/4", "FY16 Q1/2", "FY16 Q3/4",
          "FY17 Q1/Q2", "FY17 Q3/Q4", "FY18 Q1/2", "FY18 Q3/4"};
starvedTime = {7.55, 11.23, 8.58333, 6.88833, 4.65167, 1.89, 6.49833, 1.95};
satTime = {70.1483, 81.1467, 81.115, 86.5483, 84.6833, 90.685, 79.6017, 91.0133};
```

Then some prepared parts:

```
lblspec =
  Join[
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #, 0} &, labels],
   {#, "", {0, 0.01}} & /@ Range[1.5, 8, 1]
  ];

box = Graphics[{purple, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2.7, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 27];
text = "Smelter Starved (%)";
text2 = "% Time Smelter at Constraint Rate (%)";
line = Graphics[{orange, Line[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> 30];
legend = Row@{box, Spacer[5], text, Spacer[50], line, Spacer[5], text2};
```

Then auxiliary functions and a style definition:

```
style1 = {FontFamily -> "Tahoma", 11};

bar[w_][h_, {p_}] := Rectangle[{p - w/2, 0}, {p + w/2, h}] (* width, height, position *)

scale = Rescale[#, {60, 100}, {0, 12}] &; (* range of each y axis *)
```

Finally, the `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{
   {purple, bar[0.4] ~MapIndexed~ starvedTime},
   {orange, Thickness[0.0025], Line[{#2[[1]], scale @ #} & ~MapIndexed~ satTime]}
  },
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 8.5}, {0, 12}},
  GridLines -> {None, {3, 6, 9}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 12, 3], {scale @ #, #} & /@ Range[60, 100, 10]}, {lblspec, None}},
  LabelStyle -> style1, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, Style["Smelter Starved Time (%)", Bold], Spacer[{0, 10}], 
    Style["Smelter Operating at Constraint Rate (%)", Bold]},
  PlotLabel -> Style[
    "Smelter Starved Time by 6 Month Period: Base Case",
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 14],
  ImageSize -> 580,
  AspectRatio -> 0.55
] // Grid[List /@ {#, legend ~Style~ style1}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I didn't get the fonts exact, and I didn't bother to increase the space around the left and right Tick labels but otherwise I think you'll agree it's pretty close.

Comment: I agree it is very close. It's an interesting approach doing it using Graphics primitives. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Cam You are welcome.  May I know, out of curiosity, why you Accepted the other answer?  (To my eye this method is cleaner but perhaps my perspective is lacking.)

Comment: It's certainly less code. The answer from Mike was similar to the way that I originally coded it (which may not be a good thing). However, it does mean that I would have more hope of modifying it myself in the future. Your answer did get me thinking about how I do these kinds of charts but at the moment it's probably a bit too complex for my skill level.