# How to raise the LegendLayout "Row" size

Tags: legending

When using `LegendLayout->"Row"`, with a lengthy row, I get line breaks. This would seemed logic if it was confined by another structure. But if happens even when there's no "confinement":

```
LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green}, {"this is a big test", 
  "this is a big test", "this is a big test"}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

How can I change the `ItemSize`/`ImageSize` of the Legend?

(should this behavior be reported?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Tell it that you really want `n` rows by `{"Row", n}`, for example:

```
LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green}, {"this is a big test", 
"this is a big test", "this is a big test"}, 
LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}]
```

Comment: This construct for LegendLayout really needs to be inside the documentation. It is extremely useful

Answer (score 4):

To avoid line breaks You can use Grid insted ([more here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19558/5478)):

```
f[x_] := Grid[{Flatten@x}];

LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green}, {"this is a big test", 
 "this is a big test", "this is a big test"}, LegendLayout -> f]
```

**Edit**

Strange thing that I can not put pure function to `LegendLayout` option :/ If You don't want to define f outside, use: `LegendLayout->Function[{x}, Grid@{Flatten@x}]`.

Comment: try: `LegendLayout -> (Grid[{Flatten@#}] &)`, that should do the trick (for the pure function that is)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Ah, it does. I should have thought about this :p

Comment: The reason you need the parentheses is `&` has a lower precedence than `->`. If you run `FullForm[q -> #&]` you get `Function[Rule[q, Slot[1]]]`, but add parentheses: `FullForm[q -> (#&)]` you get, `Rule[q, Function[Slot[1]]]`.