# In LineLegend, how do I force the legend entries to appear in a single column?

Tags: version-9, legending

I want to create a ***single*** column `LineLegend` with at least 12 different entries.  Suppose that I define lists `colors` and `names` as follows:

```
colors = {Red, Magenta, Pink, Orange, Yellow, Green, Darker[Green], 
   Cyan, Blue, Purple, Black, Gray};
names = Table["Color " <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Length[colors]}];
```

If I use `colors[[;; 10]]` to show only the first 10 entries in `LineLegend` with `LegendLayout -> "Column"`, I get a nice single column `LineLegend`:

```
LineLegend[colors[[;; 10]], names, LegendLayout -> "Column", 
 LabelStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image: singleColumn]

However, if I show 11 or more entries, the legends become double-columned:

```
LineLegend[colors[[;; 11]], names, LegendLayout -> "Column", 
 LabelStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image: doubleColumn1]

```
LineLegend[colors, names, LegendLayout -> "Column", 
 LabelStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image: doubleColumn2]

How can I force `LineLegend` to put the legend entries in a single column?

Comment: `f[pairs_] := Grid[pairs];
LineLegend[colors, names, LegendLayout -> f, LabelStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]` gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8JGH.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a layout function as shown in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LegendLayout.html) :-

```
colors = {Red, Magenta, Pink, Orange, Yellow, Green,
   Darker[Green], Cyan, Blue, Purple, Black, Gray};
names = Table["Color " <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Length[colors]}];

table[pairs_] := TableForm[pairs, TableAlignments -> Left,
   TableSpacing -> {2, 1}];

LineLegend[colors[[;; 11]], names, LegendLayout -> table, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 24):

There is an easier answer to this (esp. if you don't want to custom-specify colors), at least in version 10, found as the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26231/how-to-raise-the-legendlayout-row-size):

```
LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]
```

All credit goes to MinHsuan Peng who answered that question, I just reposted here because I found this page first and thought other people searching for this would like to find this solution first too.

It's really disappointing (I wish I could say surprising) that this option isn't even listed in the "Possible settings for LegendLayout" in the details section of the Mathematica documentation.

Comment: Brilliant! I was so desperate finding this!