# Listplot legend in one column

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, legending, column

I am trying to plot multiple curves with ListPlot. Since I have 12 curves to plot, the legend appears in two columns. I looked into [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/in-linelegend-how-do-i-force-the-legend-entries-to-appear-in-a-single-column) but it does not work with Listplot. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Saeid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

data = Reverse@Transpose[
    Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {10, 12}]];
```

If the `ListPlot` is `Joined`

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]]
```

[image]

If not `Joined`

```
ListPlot[data,
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]]
```

[image]