# Adjusting bounding box of PlotLegends in TimelinePlot

Tags: legending

I'd like to align the elements of the `PlotLegend` in a *single* horizontal row beneath the `TimelinePlot`, as there is plenty of room for that (especially when I adjust the `Size` to be large).  Instead the internal algorithms pack the `PlotLegends` into three rows in this case.

How to fix that?

```
TimelinePlot[
 {

  <|{Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"] -> 
     Interval[{"1452", "1521"}]
    }|>,

  <|{Entity["Person", "CamilleCorot::vx57d"] -> 
     Interval[{"1796", "1875"}]
    }|>,

  <|{
    "Piet Mondrian" -> Interval[{"1872", "1944"}]
    }|>,

  <|{"Thomas Gainsborough" -> Interval[{"1727", "1788"}]
    }|>,

  <|{Entity["Person", "JanDavidszDeHeem::2gt75"] -> 
     Interval[{"1606", "1684"}]
    }|>,

  <|{"Pablo Picasso" -> Interval[{"1881", "1973"}]
    }|>,

  <|{"Hokusai" -> Interval[{"1760", "1849"}]
    }|>

  }
 ,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, 
   Black},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{Text[Style["Italian", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["French", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["American", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["British", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["Flemish", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["Spanish", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
    Text[Style["Japanese", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]]}, 
   Below],
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 PlotLayout -> "Packed",
 Background -> LightGray,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 AxesOrigin -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: If the legend is to indicate nationality, then it should be „*Dutch*“ for *de Heem*. Also the curator of knowledge in the WL should be told that „*Davidsz.*“ is an abbreviation for „*Davidszoon*“ - so there is a period missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by `Legended`ing the plot itself and then using `LegendLayout`:

```
tlp = TimelinePlot[{<|{Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"] -> 
      Interval[{"1452", "1521"}]}|>, <|{Entity["Person", 
       "CamilleCorot::vx57d"] -> 
      Interval[{"1796", "1875"}]}|>, <|{"Piet Mondrian" -> 
      Interval[{"1872", "1944"}]}|>, <|{"Thomas Gainsborough" -> 
      Interval[{"1727", "1788"}]}|>, <|{Entity["Person", 
       "JanDavidszDeHeem::2gt75"] -> 
      Interval[{"1606", "1684"}]}|>, <|{"Pablo Picasso" -> 
      Interval[{"1881", "1973"}]}|>, <|{"Hokusai" -> 
      Interval[{"1760", "1849"}]}|>}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, 
    Black}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLayout -> "Packed", 
  Background -> LightGray, ImageSize -> 600, AxesOrigin -> Center]
```

Now we add our legend. Note the `LegendLayout` function:

```
Legended[tlp,
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, Black},
   {"Italian", 
     "French", "American", "British", "Flemish", "Spanish", 
     "Japanese"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"},
   LegendLayout -> (Row[Row[#, Spacer[1]] & /@ #, Spacer[7]] &), 
   LegendMargins -> 0], Below]]
```

Resulting in:

[image]

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this than creating nested `Row`s, but I'm afraid I don't have the time to have a look.

Answer (score 4):

Just a slightly different take for readability avoiding `Slot`, using `Riffle` for the `Spacers` and constructing the graphics with centralized components (e.g. using `With`):

```
With[
  { data = 
       { <|{Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"] -> Interval[{"1452", "1521"}]}|>
       , <|{Entity["Person", "CamilleCorot::vx57d"] -> Interval[{"1796", "1875"}]}|>
       , <|{"Piet Mondrian" -> Interval[{"1872", "1944"}]}|>
       , <|{"Thomas Gainsborough" -> Interval[{"1727", "1788"}]}|>
       , <|{Entity["Person", "JanDavidszDeHeem::2gt75"] -> Interval[{"1606", "1684"}]}|>
       , <|{"Pablo Picasso" -> Interval[{"1881", "1973"}]}|>
       , <|{"Hokusai" -> Interval[{"1760", "1849"}]}|>
       }
  , colors = { Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, Black }
  , styleFunc = Function[ text, 
       Style[ text, 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]
    ]
  , labels = { "Italian", "French", "American", "British", "Flemish", "Spanish", "Japanese" }
  , layoutFunc = Function[ pairs, (* pairs = { {col1, lbl1}, ... } *)
       pairs // RightComposition[
          Flatten
          , Curry[Riffle][{Spacer[2] (* after color *), Spacer[10] (* between labels *) }] 
          , Row
       ]
    ]
  }
  ,
  TimelinePlot[ data
    , PlotStyle -> colors
    , AxesOrigin -> Center
    , AspectRatio -> 1/2
    , PlotLegends -> Curry[Placed][Bottom] @ LineLegend[
         colors,
         styleFunc /@ labels
         , LegendLayout -> layoutFunc
         , LegendMargins -> 0
      ] 
    , PlotLayout -> "Packed"
    , Background -> LightGray
    , ImageSize -> 600
  ]
]
```

[image: TimelinePlot]

Comment: That's really interesting, it didn't occur to me that you could use currying in this way!

Answer (score 4):

Per [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26756/4346), you can use the option `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}`.

```
data = {<|{Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"] -> 
     Interval[{"1452", "1521"}]}|>, <|{Entity["Person", 
      "CamilleCorot::vx57d"] -> 
     Interval[{"1796", "1875"}]}|>, <|{"Piet Mondrian" -> 
     Interval[{"1872", "1944"}]}|>, <|{"Thomas Gainsborough" -> 
     Interval[{"1727", "1788"}]}|>, <|{Entity["Person", 
      "JanDavidszDeHeem::2gt75"] -> 
     Interval[{"1606", "1684"}]}|>, <|{"Pablo Picasso" -> 
     Interval[{"1881", "1973"}]}|>, <|{"Hokusai" -> 
     Interval[{"1760", "1849"}]}|>};

labels = {Text[
      Style["Italian", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["French", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["American", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["British", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["Flemish", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["Spanish", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], 
     Text[Style["Japanese", 16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]]};

TimelinePlot[data, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[labels, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Below], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  PlotLayout -> "Packed", 
  Background -> LightGray, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  AxesOrigin -> Center
]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool (+1). So, they had 6 years to finally document this ... and did not?

Comment: That appears to be the case.

Comment: Aha, this is the real solution! I can't believe this is undocumented. I also have a hard time understanding why they used `"Row"` the string rather than `Row` the symbol...

Comment: My guess is the string version maintains consistency among other choices like "ReversedRow", etc. In addition, `LegendLayout` allows for an arbitrary function `f` and so parsing `Row` in this way would create ambiguity.

Comment: Since LineLegend accepts a LabelStyle option, you could simplify things by using `LineLegend[labels, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {16, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"}]` and dropping all of those Style/Text wrappers in the labels.