# Remove braces, {}, from around DynamicModule output?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, output-formatting, formatting

Is there a way to remove the braces from the front end output associated with `DynamicModule`?  For instance:

```
a=0;
DynamicModule[{x}, {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[If[x>.5,a=1;,{}]]}]
```

This returns a slider with braces around it.  Is there a way to avoid or remove the braces?

Comment: `Row@{Slider...`? This is what you want?

Comment: @Kuba: Yes!  But can they also be eliminated from the Dynamic[If[...]]?

Comment: @user8454 does `Dynamic[If[x > .5, a = 1;, Spacer[0]]]` do what you want?

Comment: Yes @Mr.Wizard! Sorry @Kuba! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Kuba Do you care to post both parts as an answer?

Comment: @Kuba Also include `""` as an alternative to `Spacer[0]` if you will.  I have at times found `Spacer` more robust so I tend to default to it, but I cannot at the moment remember where or why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fix to your code would be to add `Row` and `Spacer[0]`.

```
a=0;
DynamicModule[{x}, Row@{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[If[x>.5,a=1;, Spacer[0]]]}]
```

Instead of `Spacer[0]` you can use empty string: `""`, or `Invisible[""]`.

Those braces are in output because you put them there. To know more about organizing an output, take a look at documentation:

[**tutorial / Grids Rows and Columns overview**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumnsOverview.html)

there are also interesting related Q&A-s here on Mathematica.SE, for example:

[**Why use Column with Rows instead of Grid?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19555/5478)