# Long text inside a grid does not word wrap

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

If I create a simple grid with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and paste a long piece of text outside the boxes (I'm sure you can find some yourself), then that text does not break at the width of the window in *Mathematica*. Instead, you have to scroll through it with a newly appeared scroll bar at the bottom.

How can this be fixed?

As an example, you can see bellow here how the word 'also' is getting cut off.
I am typing this in, it is not the output of a cell:

[image: try1]

Really, my goal is to put text besides a picture.

So thanks to Kuba, here is an attempt to first create a Row which should WordWrap, and then turn that output cell into a text and TraditionalForm cell, and fill it in with my content:
[image: try2]
However, you can see that this breaks the text indeed, but on a new line bellow the picture, I would like to get it alongside the picture.

Comment: Something like `Grid[{{"kkkkkkkk"}, {"mmmmmm"}}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 10]`?

Comment: I just updated the question. what you say works for a grid, but this thing I think is a GridBox and it doesnt have ItemSize

Comment: `your grid // Grid[#, ItemSize -> 5] &`

Comment: 2D input is handy but you have less control, please take a look at links in [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32624/5478)

Comment: @Kuba, Its a text cell, so I can't execute it?

Comment: Create Input cell and execute it, you can hide/close it just after.

Comment: @Kuba Ah, so reading that Q&A it seems that Grid does not wrap for some reason, but Row would. Now how can I get A Row, Column expression like that into my text cell? Do i have to define a new shortcut?

Comment: @Kuba, So I tried that but it breaks the text onto a new line bellow the other cell, Ill attach a screenshot above. This is really not what I want.

Comment: You can use Row on B I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want, but `Grid` does wrap. Here is an example:

```
longtext = StringJoin@RandomChoice[CharacterRange[" ", "z"], 500];
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 200];
Grid[
 {{Image[img, ImageSize -> All], longtext}},
 Alignment -> {Center, Top}
]
```

The `ImageSize->All` ensures that the image doesn't get resized.

[image: output]

Comment: OP is not using Grid, but grid with Ctrl+Enter/Ctrl+, then it just an array formated to GridBox.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any easy way to do what ask for, but a not-so-easy way is to edit to open the raw cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and, in the `GridBox` expression you find there, add the option `GridBoxItemSize`.

```
Cell[BoxData[
  GridBox[{
    {
     RowBox[{
     "The", " ", "quick", " ", "brown", " ", "fox", " ", "jumped", " ", "over", " ", "the", 
      " ", "lazy", " ", "dog"}], 
     RowBox[{
     "The", " ", "quick", " ", "brown", " ", "fox", " ", "jumped", " ", "over", " ", "the",
      " ", "lazy", " ", "dog"}]},
    {
     RowBox[{
     "The", " ", "quick", " ", "brown", " ", "fox", " ", "jumped", " ", "over", " ", "the", 
      " ", "lazy", " ", "dog"}], 
     RowBox[{
     "The", " ", "quick", " ", "brown", " ", "fox", " ", "jumped", " ", "over", " ", "the", 
     " ", "lazy", " ",  "dog"}]}
   }, 
     GridBoxDividers->{"Rows"->{{True}},"Columns"->{{True}}},
     GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns"->{{15}}}]], 
  "Text"]//DisplayForm
```

[image: grid.png]

Note 1: the postfix `// DisplayForm` is only there because I found it convenient to work this out in an input cell. Don't use it when you editing the raw cell.

Note 2: In your case, you probably want `GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {Automatic, 15}}`. At least, that is the setting I would try as a first approximation.